# ostream operator overloading for unsigned char in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream, unsigned-char

Given:

```
typedef struct { char val[SOME_FIXED_SIZE]; } AString;
typedef struct { unsigned char val[SOME_FIXED_SIZE]; } BString;
```

I want to add ostream operator `<<` available for `AString` and `BString`.

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const AString &str)
{ 
   out.write(str.val, SOME_FIXED_SIZE);
   return out;
}
```

If I do the same for `BString`, the compiler complains about `invalid conversion from 'const unsigned char*' to 'const char*'`. The `ostream.write` does not have `const unsigned char*` as argument.

It seems `<<` itself accepts the `const unsigned char`, so I try something like this

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BString &str)
{ 
    for (int i=0; i<SOME_FIXED_SIZE; i++)
    {
        out<<str.val[i];
    }
    return out;
}
```

Can someone tell me if this is right/good practice or there are some better ways?
welcome any comments!

Comment: I thought chars are by default unsigned.

Comment: @balki That very much depends on your compiler settings; but in general, no.

Comment: The question is, what do you use `BString` for? If you really mean a textual string, then use the `char` version and all is well. If you have arbitrary binary data, then just printing to the output might not show anything meaningful or break your terminal. So why bother with two string classes?

Comment: two string classes are from legacy code. Honestly, I do not know why. I will figure it out and come back for this point.

Comment: @balki: The standard does not describe the signedness of `char`. In fact, `unsigned char`, `signed char` and `char` are three distinct datatypes, which you should keep in mind especially when overloading things and writing templates.

Comment: @balki: Even if, on your platform, `char` is an unsigned type, it's still distinct from `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest solution is to create an `std::string`, e.g.:

```
out << std::string(str.val, str.val + sizeof(str.val));
```

However, the question is: do you want formatted or unformatted output?
For unformatted output, as ugly as it is, I'd just use a
`reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: std::string() doesn't provide any benefit here, reinterpret_cast sounds better

Comment: `std::string` is clearer and more easily understood.  And it doesn't raise a red flag like `reinterpret_cast` should.

Comment: it allocates heap memory and makes internal copy. IMHO used in right place and commented `reinterpret_cast` sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about casting it to `char*`:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BString &str)
{ 
   out.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(str.val), sizeof(str.val));
   return out;
}
```

Comment: It would require a `reinterpret_cast`, not a `static_cast`.